# Make @Transactional and @Rollback work with Spring Boot Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and tests with `@SpringBootTest`.
I'm trying to have my database in the same state for each test.
My test class is annotated with `@Transactional` and `@Rollback`.
And the services I'm testing are also annotated with `@Transactional`.
From what I understand while activating TransactionManager TRACE logs, the Spring Boot app transactions are committed and the test transaction is rolled back as expected.
The issue comes from the fact that there are 2 different transactions created with my setup: one for test and one for the app.

Do you know what I could do to have the transaction created in the test be the same in the app?

Example code:
https://github.com/sey/transactional
You will see that GreetingsResourceTest fails because I think there are 2 different contexts not sharing transaction.
However GreetingsServiceTest works as expected as there is not a specific application context created during the test.

Comment: 1) you don't need Rollback because Spring Boot Test always rolls back the transaction if Transactional is present. 2) why do you think there are two transactions? Spring Boot Test propagates the same transaction to your service.

Comment: Show your test.

Comment: I added an example project to demonstrate my issue. If you can have a look and tell me what is wrongly configured. As @SimonMartinelli stated I didn't put `@Rollback` on the test as the default behaviour is to rollback the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Spring has a propagation level e that represents transaction propagation behaviors for use with the Transactional annotation. Is the only way that you can overwrite how Spring will create Transactions using @Transactional:

```
MANDATORY
Support a current transaction, throw an exception if none exists.

NESTED
Execute within a nested transaction if a current transaction exists, behave like      PROPAGATION_REQUIRED else.

NEVER
Execute non-transactionally, throw an exception if a transaction exists.

NOT_SUPPORTED
Execute non-transactionally, suspend the current transaction if one exists.

REQUIRED
Support a current transaction, create a new one if none exists.

REQUIRES_NEW
Create a new transaction, and suspend the current transaction if one exists.

SUPPORTS
Support a current transaction, execute non-transactionally if none exists.
```